# replace one list with another list in python in the same array

Tags: python

i can always change bwtween list if I do not have them in One array...

If I have an array having more than one list

```
 a = [[2,3,4,],[8,14,13],[12,54,98]]
```

how do I replace `a[2]` with `a[0]`??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>For your original post:</strike>

```
a = [[2,3,4,],[8,14,13],[12,54,98]]
a[2] = a[0]
```

then `a` will be:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [8, 14, 13], [2, 3, 4]]
```

**Update** based on comment to sdolan below:

If you want to exchange the two, you could simply do this:

```
a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]
```

giving

```
[[12, 54, 98], [8, 14, 13], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: @charlottechahin one more update (even simpler to swap first and last element)

Answer (score 2):

Lists are mutable so you probably want to replace list items, not the lists themselves:

```
a[2][:] = a[0]
```

If you want to swap lists rather than replace them then:

```
a[0], a[2] = a[2], a[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign it:

```
>>> a = [[2,3,4,],[8,14,13],[12,54,98]]
>>> 
>>> a[2] = list(a[0]) # list() to create a new copy
>>> a
[[2, 3, 4], [8, 14, 13], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer.. I missed something in my question I wanted to flip them... I would like to end up with a= [[12, 54, 98], [8, 14, 13], [2, 3, 4]]... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The way you asked this is to just change the array from 
`a = [[2,3,4,],[8,14,13],[12,54,98]]`
to
`a = [[2,3,4,],[8,14,13],[2,3,4,]]`

so you can do `a[2] = a[0]`

but if you want to swap them, you will need something like:

```
b = a[0]
a[0] = a[2]
a[2] = b
```

EDIT for shorthand:

`a[0], a[2] = a[2], a[0]`

Comment: You don't need the intermediate `b`: `a[0], a[2] = a[2], a[0]` works.  [Not that you can tell when they're equal..]

Comment: @charlottechahine don't forget to upvote anything you feel was helpful and mark an answer.